# Configure sendmail to accept connection from one other IP address

Tags: sendmail

I have a RubyOnRails application running on the same server that runs sendmail. The application sends out (no need to receive) emails via the local sendmail.

Now I intend to move sendmail to a dedicated server. How do I make sendmail on that server accept connections from my application on the other server?

I modified sendmail.mc from

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

to

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp')dnl
```

I have also added to /etc/mail/access:

```
Connect:198.xxx.xxx.xxx                             RELAY
```

then ran

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

and restarted sendmail.

Trying to connect from my app server with telnet on port 25 to the mail server gives me:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is reported by `netstat -ant | grep :25`?

Comment: Also do a `iptables -nL` on your mail server and see if port 25/tcp inbound is allowed

Answer (score 1):

After adding

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea')dnl
```

to sendmail.mc everything works.